# How to add {props.children} to a React component

Tags: reactjs

i have many components which have `{props.children}` deeply nested inside.
considery DRY principle is there a way to add this using some React pattern.

**example**
let's say i have two components,

**Comp1.js**

```
import React from "react";

const Comp1 = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{props.children}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Comp1;
```

**Comp2.js**

```
import React from "react";

const Comp2 = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>{props.children}</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Comp2;
```

if you see above code we have both **Comp1** and **Comp2** have line of code {props.children} repeated inside.

what i want now is some function which will add this line of code, something like below,

```
    const addPropsChildrenToComp  = (Comp)=>{
      return(
        (props)=>{
///do somehting here
        }
      )
    }


const Comp1 = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1></h1>
    </div>
  );
};

Comp1WithPropsChildren = addPropsChildrenToComp(Comp1)
```

using HOC doesn't work because, in HOC we never modify passed component.
anyway to aceve this.?

to get more idea of my problem see this demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-http-pd1yu

in there i woul like to see CompWithPropsChildren component render props.children inside it.

Comment: but... why ????

Comment: But where will you add the children? How will you know that?

Comment: I don't think this is called a repeating code. There is no logic it's just you are rendering children at a different node.

Comment: Comp1WithPropsChildren = addPropsChildrenToComp(Comp1)
Comp2WithPropsChildren = addPropsChildrenToComp(Comp2), this is that you are trying basically addPropsChildrenToComp will take the passed component and add it ? is that what you are looking for

Comment: i am creating a ui library where i have many container components.
i just want to remove this  repeated code. if i want to handle the props.children in complex function i could do it in one common place right??

let me know if that's a bad practise

Comment: use render props?

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what you're trying to get to, and you can accomplish this just using another component.

```
import React from "react";
import ChildComp from "./ChildComp";

const Comp1 = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ChildComp {...props} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Comp1;
```

```
import React from "react";

const ChildComp = props => {
   return <h1>{props.children}</h1>
}
```

Assuming your `ChildComp` has some complex logic you don't want to duplicate, this will make it reusable for you.

Comment: sorry , but that wasn't what i was trying to do.